# Magento Connector in Mule 3.5

Tags: magento, mule

I have tried creating Megento connector example program as given in the Megento connector vedio link.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCbuqHLCiOg

My flow is:

```
<magento:config name="MagentoConnector" username="${magento.username}" password="${magento.password}" address="${magento.address}" doc:name="Magento">
    <magento:connection-pooling-profile initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW"/>
</magento:config>
<flow name="ShoppingCartOPerations" doc:name="ShoppingCartOPerations">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="shoppingCartOperation" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <flow-ref name="CreateProduct" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    <set-payload value="Product Id is #[groovy:message.getProperty('productId')]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
<sub-flow name="CreateProduct" doc:name="CreateProduct">
    <magento:create-product config-ref="MagentoConnector" type="simple" set="1" sku="simple_sku" storeViewIdOrCode="4" doc:name="Create Product" address="https://sashistore.gostorego.com/api/v2_soap" password="gdskey" username="gdssrao">
        <magento:attributes name="SampleProduct" description="TestProduct" short_description="creating sample product" weight="100" status="1" visibility="4" price="100" tax_class_id="1"/>
    </magento:create-product>
    <set-property propertyName="productId" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Store Product id"/>
    <magento:update-inventory-stock-item config-ref="MagentoConnector" productId="#[groovy:message.getProperty('productId')]" doc:name="Update Stock">
        <magento:catalog-inventory-stock-item qty="33" is_in_stock="100" min_qty="10"/>
    </magento:update-inventory-stock-item>
</sub-flow>
```

---

ERROR 2014-01-29 23:48:48,521 [[magentotest].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: null. Type: class org.mule.api.ConnectionException
ERROR 2014-01-29 23:48:48,524 [[magentotest].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your plaintext connection attributes (username, password, address) in magento:create-product and then you have them as application properties in magento:config. That does not really make sense, as you only need to define the attributes once (in the config element) when you use config-ref in the other elements. Since you are having a connection failure, I would guess that you have incorrect properties in the config element. Try using the attributes from magento:create-product, instead.

EDIT: I checked the [WSDL](https://sashistore.gostorego.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1) for your Magento API, and it seems that you have incorrect address

Try using https://sashistore.gostorego.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/ instead.

EDIT2: I got the WSDL URL for Magento API v2 from [the Magento documentation](https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html). See [this](http://www.herongyang.com/WSDL/WSDL-11-Extension-SOAP-11-address-Location-.html) page for explanation on how to get the address for Web services from WSDL.

Comment: Cool !! its working with this URL. Can you please provide me how to find the correct URL. The old url is also working in the Magento connection creation but failing while calling operations?

Comment: No magic, I just checked the WSDL for your service, as described in the Magento documentation (https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html). WSDL defines of a "port" (typically with a URL) where to send the SOAP calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
<magento:config name="MagentoConnector" username="gdssrao" password="gdskey" address="https://sashistore.gostorego.com/api/v2_soap" doc:name="Magento">
    <magento:connection-pooling-profile initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW"/>
</magento:config>
<flow name="ShoppingCartOPerationsFlow" doc:name="ShoppingCartOPerationsFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="shoppingCartOperation" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <flow-ref name="CreateProductFlow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-payload value="Product Id is #[groovy:message.getProperty('productId')]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
<sub-flow name="CreateProductFlow" doc:name="CreateProductFlow">
    <magento:create-product config-ref="MagentoConnector" type="simple" set="1" sku="simple_sku" storeViewIdOrCode="4" doc:name="Create Product">
    <magento:attributes name="SampleProduct" description="TestProduct" short_description="creating sample product" weight="100"  visibility="4" />
    </magento:create-product>
     <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-property propertyName="productId" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Store Product id"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <magento:update-inventory-stock-item config-ref="MagentoConnector" productId="#[groovy:message.getProperty('productId')]" doc:name="Update Stock">
        <magento:catalog-inventory-stock-item   />
    </magento:update-inventory-stock-item>
</sub-flow>
```